# Create custom CRUD on elastic search

Tags: java, elasticsearch, plugins, elastic-stack, semantic-web

So, I have an application that extracts keywords from an elastic search document. I need to somehow run this application when my elastic search receives a new document to index so that the keywords generated get registered and stored with the document. Is there anyway to create a Plugin that extracts the keywords as soon as the document arrives?

Comment: hi, have you checked my reply? was that of any help?

Comment: Yes it was helpful, but I have a restriction on the amount of open ports I can use, so adding an endpoint to my app might not be approved.

Answer (score 0):

"I need to somehow run this application when my elastic search receives a new document to index"

what you are describing requires a combination of an Ingest Pipeline and Ingest Plugin with a listener for indexing events.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/ingest.html

the ingest pipleline lets you manipulate the incoming JSON, and the listener provides a hook for you to trigger any code you want.

Elastic.co don't usually provide good documentation for these kinds of things, but checkout the examples they have and their GitHub:
https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/tree/master/plugins

Answer (score -1):

I cannot think of an Elasticsearch plugin (I'm not aware of such a thing), but I'd rather recommend using Logstash, and configure the [Elasticsearch input plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-elasticsearch.html) to listen to updates in your cluster and use other plugins to react accordingly. To enable Logstash communicating with your application, an idea might be to add a REST endpoint to your app and let Logstash sending requests to that endpoint by using the [Http output plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-http.html).